# asp.net assembly redirection windows server 2008

Tags: asp.net, windows, redirect

Can anyone tell me where the Asp.net Assembly Configuration is so I can set the assembly bindings for the GAC on Server 2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the assembly redirect in the machine.config or web.config to have it apply globally. see c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config